# How to sum time durations in days greater than number of days in current month?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, worksheet-function

I got many time durations in "hh:mm:ss" and want to display the sum of these as "dd hh:mm:ss". `Excel 2007` does this correct as long the summation number of days is **less or equal** the number of days in current month.

It is not possible to overload days using "[dd]" as you can with hours, minutes and seconds.

*Duration examples*

```
A1 00:54:12
A2 14:02:00
A3 12:20:01
A4 23:59:59
A5 =Sum(A1:A4)
```

Which non-array formula can I use to achieve wanted format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the formula

```
=floor(sum(A1:A4))&" "&floor(mod(sum(A1:A4),1)*24)&":"&floor(mod(mod(sum(A1:A4),1)*24,1)*60)&":"&mod(mod(mod(sum(A1:A4),1)*24,1)*60,1)*60
```

which will generate the result as a string with the days hours:minutes:seconds.
To correct the fractional seconds, and to ensure each of hours/minutes/seconds get two digits, you should pad them like this: `TEXT(formula_section,"00")`

The final formula would then be:

```
=floor(sum(A1:A4))&" "&TEXT(floor(mod(sum(A1:A4),1)*24),"00")&":"&TEXT(floor(mod(mod(sum(A1:A4),1)*24,1)*60),"00")&":"&TEXT(mod(mod(mod(sum(A1:A4),1)*24,1)*60,1)*60,"00")
```

Comment: Thanks. You have a misplaced "=".
Padding was easily done with " TEXT(hour/min/sec-part,"00") " as its only numbers.